# Windows 7 removed GRUB

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recovering grub after installing windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83771/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-7)

Currently i have Ubuntu 12.04. I want to install Win7 together with ubuntu. I know that if perform a install of windows, win will take the boot loader and will give me only option to select windows. 
If i can dual boot them together, and not loose ubuntu, how to do that?

Comment: Follow this Documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot.This should help you.

Comment: beeju's link didn't work for me. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the best way, but the way I do it is to let Windows have it's way and install, hiding Ubuntu from me in the process. Then I switch off and reboot into Super Grub Boot Disc. This finds all the OSs, including Ubuntu, and so I choose Ubuntu to boot into, and then just re-install Grub. It works at least. You need to burn a copy of S-G-B-D, but it's very handy to keep in your toolkit anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and that meant i had to start with windows and then ubuntu since when you install windows after ubuntu windows tends to overwrite grub. After some time things changed and now you can start with either, then you can fix grub with Boot-Repair.

[How to use Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Cheers