# How to recover Grub for Ubuntu after windows 7 installation 

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recovering grub after installing windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83771/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-7)

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 then I installed Windows 7 .
But as soon as I restarted my Win 7 there was no Boot Option to select from...
The boot option to select operating system just disappeared.
I tried reinstalling Ubuntu 12.04 but no use...
Still my PC boots straight into Windows 7.