# Is it possible to install Windows using Wine?

Tags: wine

I'm trying to switch to Windows 8 on a desktop computer. I purchased and downloaded the digital setup (I wanted an installation disk but apparently it's unavailable), but it won't open! I have Wine configured to Windows 7.

Comment: plz add some more details?

Comment: did you want to dual boot windows with the previously installed ubuntu?

Comment: that would be nice

Comment: but not if it's not doable

Comment: There is no windows DVD. So you're saying I'm screwed?

Comment: I mean I have no windows DVD

Answer (score 0):

Wine was not designed to install entire Operating Systems. You can't install anything but applications using Wine. To install Windows you have to:

- [In case you want multi-boot with Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/6321/169736):

  1. Restart the system.
  2. Boot a Ubuntu live cd
  3. Open Gparted
  4. Modify your partitions to create a free space.
  5. Create a NTFS partition in the free space created.
  6. Reboot with the Windows DVD.
  7. Install Windows
  8. [Repair the GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83771/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-7).
- In case you only want to install Windows replacing everything else:

  1. Restart the system and boot with the Windows installation media.
  2. Install Windows