# startup after installation problem in choosing w7 and ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, windows-7, startup

I installed ubuntu 12.04 with using DVD beside my Windows 7. Installation was completed. Then it asked for restarting the system. After that system goes to Windows 7 without asking me to choose between Windows 7 and ubuntu..

Comment: Run boot-repair.

Answer (score 0):

You should use your startup cd/dvd to start an ubuntu live session, and then either install boot-repair and run it, or follow the detailed steps from here: [Recovering GRUB after installing Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83771/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-7)