# New laptop won't boot after installing Ubuntu 14.04 on SSD

Tags: boot, 14.04, ssd, bios

I removed the HDD from a Toshiba Computer I bought today and installed a 250GB SSD. After installing it, I immediately installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it from a USB drive. Everything went fine during installation, but when I restarted I got the message

`Reboot and select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot Device and press a key`.

That message came up after a nano-second screen that says `Checking Media Presence` and then `No Media Present`.

When I reboot using the USB stick, I can see the SSD drive and it has the OS written on it and it looks like it's been partitioned correctly.

**Can someone please tell me what I need to do to get my computer to boot up?**

- I read something about how the Secure boot and CSM or UEFI might be a factor, but I'm not experienced enough with new Bios to know how to configure those settings.
- I also read about Grub probably not installing on the SSD and I might just have to fix Grub for it to work, but I haven't been able to do that through the Ubuntu running of the USB stick.

Any help or links to good threads would be very helpful. If you have any questions, I would be very happy to help you in helping me.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7407446/

Comment: The installer will work with secure boot on. But did you install with secure boot in UEFI mode, UEFI mode, or BIOS boot mode. How you boot installer is how it installs. You can copy the link Boot-Repair gives you and post it in your first post. Then we can see exactly how you installed. Review this, but if not dual booting you can skip all the Windows issues. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Can you get into the hardware system settings (a.k.a. BIOS)?

Comment: I can. I am currently re-installing 14.04 in legacy mode like a link that was on the page 'oldfred' suggested. I'll update on the install as soon as it finishes.

Comment: YES!!! It installed and booted up in CSM (legacy) mode. Thanks oldfred for the link! I would have liked it up install and work out of the box in UEFI, but I'll take it. Maybe I'll change it up when I add Win7 in the future. Thanks to all that helped!

Comment: please verify if you have this structure: /boot/efi/EFI/boot/BOOTx64.EFI and the other files - [grub.cfg, grubx64.efi, MokManager.efi, shimx64.efi] you must boot with your USB stick, verify the HDD directory and copy BOOTx64.EFI from USB stick to HDD Telmo Costa

Comment: Pro Tip: If you want to install Ubuntu on a SSD, make sure you put SATA in IDE mode, else grub2 won't install.

Comment: For UEFI installs, you may need to disable Secure Boot in your BIOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recovering GRUB after installing Windows 7?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/83771/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-7)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to link to here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows I know it says "windows 7" but the same instructions apply based upon the information you provided in the screenshot, you have no grub installed to the MBR. These instructions outline exactly what you need to do to install grub to the MBR and this is what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with laptop BIOS things but I've ever tried grub-fix and use it as a way of installing my own live system.

Though I've never tried to fix grub in 14.04 but it should be OK.
So would you please tell where you get stuck while fixing grub?

Also,the following link may help.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: I tried boot repair and it said there was an error and I have the url it gave me, but I don't really know what to do that that page of data. I have been using that last link you posted, and I get stuck at " grub-install /dev/sda". When I type that in I get "Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory."

Answer (score 0):

I installed 14.04 on a laptop with UEFI and it's not quite as straightforward as with a conventional BIOS.

I suggest you go into the BIOS (usually by tapping <kbd>F2</kbd> repeatedly on bootup) and ensure that <kbd>F12</kbd> is not disabled. Having it enabled will allow for a "one time" boot.

Try rebooting the machine and hold down <kbd>F12</kbd> as soon as you power up. My boot menu doesn't come up on a conventional boot. I have to use <kbd>F12</kbd> to get to it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't work. I can get the drive to be recognized, but somehow it doesn't load Ubuntu. Thanks anyway.