# want to switch from ubuntu 14.04 to windows7 using usb

Tags: 13.04

I was using windows7 and installed ubuntu 13.04 which became the only os of my laptop.
Now i want to reinstall windows7 again.I am unable to do so. please help

Comment: Just learn to search the site...

Comment: If the problem is in using Ubuntu to make bootable USB media to install Windows, see [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick with Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/289559/22949)

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Have a Linux distribution (Ubuntu) on a live CD handy before following the steps below.

Create partitions for Windows 7 using GParted in Ubuntu.
Boot the Windows 7 disk and install it on the partition created in the previous step. (Windows will not provide you with the option of choosing Ubuntu). So Ubuntu would seem unusable.
Recover Ubuntu by using a live CD (or live USB) and following the steps mentioned in Ask Ubuntu question [Recovering GRUB after installing Windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83771/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-7) 
(at the end, you should have the option of choosing the operating system from the GRUB menu.)