# having different operating systems on ubuntu

Tags: grub2

I have seen this computer where when the computer boots up, the grub screen lets him choose operating systems. as the four ubuntu choices like ubuntu recovery and stuff are still there, there is a fifth choice that says windows seven loader. is that possible to do on my computer( Ubuntu 12.04 ). if so, please suggest how.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but usually it is best to install first windows 7, and then ubuntu.

It is possible to install windows 7 after installing ubuntu, but I had all sort of problems, and needed to reinstall windows each month. 
Anyhow you can try, you will need at least 20 GB of free space, preferably on a new partition. After installing it, here you can find how to restore grub:
[Recovering GRUB after installing Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83771/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-7)

Comment: so there is no way i can get windows without deleting the ubuntu?

Comment: @belay neh you can do it, just make an empty partition of ~20 GB, insert your windows DVD, USB and install windows on that new partition! Make the partition NTFS to be sure, that you accidentally don't wipe out yout ubuntu partition

Comment: You'll want to follow up by fixing grub see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/83771/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-7?lq=1

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but how do i make a new partition?

Answer (score 0):

All right. You also can get it. It is mostly that you should install linux os , such as ubuntu or other linux, after installing windows os firstly. The reason that linux will manage grub boot rather than windows. you know, you should install windows, such as windows 7.

Then, you may met some issues if you use UEFI boot's compute rather than grub boot's compute. I can solved it by these steps. Here is that:

1. First, you must close the security boot and fastboot options in bios.
2. In terminal, to do sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair.
3. To do sudo apt-get update
4. To do 'sudo apt-get install boot-repair' for installing boot-repair.
5. After installed it, you should do sudo boot-repair.

Then, reboot your pc. You can see that the list windows7 UEFI of grub lists in screen.Choose it, and enter. Now, if everything is ok, your windows will can works well.