# Will upgrading to windows 10 affect my dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, windows-7

I'm currently running Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 with dual boot. I want to upgrade to Windows 10, but I would like my Ubuntu to be untouched. How do I go about it?

Comment: Probably. See : http://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue

Comment: After installing windows you cannot access grub. So you need to reinstall grub. I am not sure how it works with windows 10. You may find answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/83771/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-7

Comment: My recommendation: **Do not upgrade to Windows 10.** I have spent a whole day trying to upgrade my version of Windows 7 to the free upgrade, and was forced to clear *30 GB* just for the install. On top of that, I never completed the installation, because it took *ten hours* to download, and I got impatient when it asked to clear *more* space! Do as you wish, but I'm staying with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04!

Answer (score 0):

Nope it won't unless you don't touch your Ubuntu partition. After updating or even installing from live media. Just open Ubuntu and  update your grub.
I did few days ago everything is running fine.