# kernel panic and Stack with CapsLock and ScrollLock

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel

I just installed ubuntu 14.04 in a machine with ASUS H81M-K (Bios 1002 8/12/14) with pre-existing Windows 7.  The system is dual boot with one HDD.

While there was no problem during installation and live use, the problem is that the installed version does not boot.

The grub starts Ok, the win7 starts ok but when ubuntu is selected the computer is stack with CapsLock and ScrollLock leds flashing.

I tried grub-repair with no lack (http://paste.ubuntu.com/14856595/)

I also changed the secure boot option to allow Other OS boot 
and I have set the boot flag ON for sda5.

Any suggestions more than welcome!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was lucky. After some trials and boot-repairs  (e.g like the description in [Recovering GRUB after installing Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83771/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-7)) I found out that the problem was caused by the version of the kernel.

On grub menu I selected advanced options where there was the choice between
the 3.19.0-25-generic version which did not work (and was the same as the default option from grub) and the 3.13.0-77-generic version which ACTUALLY WORKΕD OK !!! 
:)

So I changed the default version in Ubuntu option from the grub menu as well and
everything is OK!