# How do I find out if I have a separate boot partiton from the Live CD?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

I am currently trying to rebuild my GRUB after reinstalling Windows 7 and [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83771/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-7) says I need to perform an extra step if I have separate boot partition.

I tried to look it up but from what I could see I can only find info on how to see the boot partition in a proper install and not while running the Live CD.

My `sda1` partition has the boot asterisk when I run `fdisk -l` says it has id 7
 and is a HPFS/NTFS/exFAT and shows 100Mib (23 Mib) used in GParted.

Is this the boot partition I am meant to mount? Or, is this only for Windows 7? Is there some kind of Ubuntu boot partition I do not have?

`sda2` is my Windows 7 partition
`sda3` is the extended partition that contains:

- `sda5` (main Linux partition)
- `sda6` (Linux swap partition)

I do not know if I ever had an `sda4` partition.

I tried to rebuild the GRUB using the same guide before without mounting a separate boot partition so I am not sure as I did not think I had one and it booted to Windows 7 as always. I am not sure if that is relevant in anyway.

Comment: You don't have a separate /boot partition.

Comment: Windows installs or major upgrades has been known to delete a logical Linux partition in the extended partition. Do you show space in extended partition. Issue has been wtih all versions of Windows since XP: http://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue/655080#655080 If you want more info post your partitions in first post: `sudo parted -l` Or post link to summary report: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 1):

You can check your fstab to see if you ever had a boot partition.
Boot with a live CD and mount your main partition (sda5).

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
```

Then show the contents of the fstab file

```
cat /mnt/etc/fstab
```

If you ever had a boot partition on e.g. sda4 you would see a line like this:

```
/dev/sda2    /boot     ext3     defaults    0  0
```

Comment: OP wrote the he has the partition "sda5 (main linux partition)". Hopefully Windows has not deleted the data and it will mount.