# grub doesn't locate ubuntu after windows fresh install on a dual boot system

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2

I was running ubuntu 16.04 and windows 7 on a dual boot system. Grub was properly showing entries for both OSes. Due to some issue I had to re-install windows, boot loader of which took over grub on MBR location. 
I reinstalled grub on MBR following below link:
http://www.av8n.com/computer/htm/grub-reinstall.htm
but got that 'Minimal Bash line editing...' grub screen after reboot. It seemed like grub was unable to locate any OS installation. I further followed 
[Recovering GRUB after installing Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83771/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-7)
tutorial. But 'sudo update-grub' gives this error:
libsudo_util.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

also tried 'boot repair' tool but it gives this error:
"enable a repository containing the [linux] packages in the software sources of ............16.04LTS(sda7)"

During original installation, I first installed Win7, and then ubuntu16.04 for which I created only 3 partitions: /, /home and swap area. Then for grub, gave location /sda. /dev/sda7 is my "/" directory and /dev/sda5 is my "/home". Later I also installed another kernel (for learning purpose) in my /home directory (as 'Linux' is being shown as 'type' for both /home and / in below image)

Also, below I am attaching result of 'fdisk -l' below:
[image: fdisk_results]

Please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: Which of the two Linux partitions  (/dev/sda5 and /dev/sda7) is your `/home` and is your `root` ("/")?

Comment: /dev/sda7 is my "/", and /dev/sda5 is my /home. The reason for 'type' being shown as 'Linux' for both of these partitions is because I installed another kernel (for learning purpose) in my /home.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

As far as update-grub is considered file libsudo_util.so.0 is not present in it's proper location.First type the command

> locate libsudo_util.so.0

If you get any output then link the location to correct location

> sudo ln -s current location /usr/lib/sudo/libsudo_util.so.0

If you did not get any output in locate you need to download the file and place it in /usr/lib/sudo folder.