# Install Windows 10 on a partition with ubuntu 16 already installed

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I want to start by saying that I know this question has been asked a lot, but the 10~15 articles and posts I've read all assume that the reader is knowledgeable on the subject, and I'm not.

So, I currently have ubuntu 16 installed on a dell latitude 6430u (if that matters). Basically what I've gathered is that I would want to install some windows 10 software on a flash drive and create a new partition on my SSD so that I could dual boot into windows 10 (switching by pressing f12 on start up to get into the bios). Now, I can't fully understand how I'm supposed to do most of that. I'm seeing a lot of installing/using grub but I'm not sure what it's saying. Any way I could get some pointers?

Some places are saying it's easier to whipe ubuntu and install windows 10, then reinstall ubuntu, but I would prefer to avoid that. Thanks

Edit: I think my question is different than the given duplicate because they're talking about windows 7. Also using cd drives, which I don't have.

Comment: Installing an OS requires some knowledge so, you better get it before trying.

Answer (score 0):

GRUB (GRand Unified Bootloader), as far as i'm aware, is a pre-OS boot loading package that allows you to select the OS you wish to use.

I imagine that a lot of people are saying to partition your drive and install windows. That way, GRUB should detect both systems and give you the choice on boot (with a simple UI) of which OS you want. The issue with this is Window's own bootloader will boot Windows instead of allowing GRUB to allow the selection, or cause conflict with GRUB.

This can be got around by repairing GRUB after the windows installation. This can be done by booting from a Ubutntu Live CD/DVD/USB. This is probably the reason why people are saying to install windows, then Ubuntu, as Ubuntu's version of GRUB would then be the primary bootloader.

I imagine the below link may help if you want to keep your current Ubuntu partition and install windows, but repair GRUB:
[Recovering GRUB after installing Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83771/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-7)