# Help with dual boot: BIOS changed and I can no longer access Linux Ubuntu already installed

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

Two years ago, I downloaded the latest version of Linux Ubuntu to do dual boot with windows 7.

In this configuration, I do not remember what BIOS version was there, but I was always asked to choose which operating system I would like to start. Sorry if I'm saying something wrong, because I really do not know this in the depth I'd like.

A couple of months ago I decided to reinstall the copy of windows 7, but instead of backing up data (from windows) directly on an external hard drive, I decided to access these personal files through the Ubuntu OS, just copying them on the Ubuntu desktop in an organized way. I was pretending to copy them back to windows 7 after reinstalling it.

The problem is that I am no longer able to access Ubuntu (where my files are) since the new installation of Windows 7 also reinstalled the original BIOS. This BIOS does not give boot options and also does not give access to Ubuntu.

Windows recognizes the existence of the partition where the old Ubuntu was, but I can not access the data from there.

As an alternative to trying to get access to that data, I've downloaded a current version of Ubuntu, burned it (Live-CD), but even through Try-on live Ubuntu version, I cannot get access to the Ubuntu partition: it just shows some general archives but not personal data (such as desktop items, etc.).

If I understand correctly what happened, what can I do to change the BIOS and recover access to the version of Ubuntu that is already installed on my computer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recovering GRUB after installing Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83771/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-7)

Comment: If you machine is BIOS & had windows 7 on it; you may have been using GNU Grub to select which OS you wanted to use. A re-install of windows will overwrite the MBR which caused grub to boot (grub is a boot-loader asking you which of many OSes you have installed you wish to boot). The link provides a few fixes if it's what I assume; personally I'd use the 39 upvote answer by choice, or 55 upvote second, but I gather many like the easier boot-repair 17 upvote answer (which can be done from live-media)

Comment: Windows in BIOS mode has a bug that does not write the Linux partition back into partition table. It is still on drive, just not in partition table. Windows 7 to Windows 10 MBR partition missing
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2288988 &
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2290190 & Parted rescue seems easier than testdisk
https://askubuntu.com/questions/665445/upgraded-to-windows-10-on-dual-boot-and-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-partition